# How to retrieve text from a TextBox that was created programatically

Tags: c#, winforms

Alright, so I have a form set up that contains a label and a button. When the button is pressed it creates several labels and and two textfields in a specific area.

I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to retrieve the text from those textfields and store it in a public string.

Any help would be wonderful and greatly appreciated.

Edit: As per request.

```
        TextBox playertextbox = new TextBox();
        playertextbox.Location = new Point(460, 200);
        this.Controls.Add(playertextbox);
```

Comment: Can you show some code? Like the code that you use to create the textboxes

Comment: Couldn't you use `playertextbox.Text` later in the code?

Comment: Give the control a name , and then you can use controls.Find("name") to get the control

Comment: check this question ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023722/how-to-dynamically-generate-textbox-and-collect-data-entered-by-user

Comment: @nrodic I can't do that, the button that retrieves the text is also created programatically and has Its own eventhandler that handles the text. The problem is, whenever I try and use .Text to retrieve it; It always comes out null, even when there is text in the textbox.

Comment: @pro This is a question relating to winforms, not relating to databases or web projects.

Comment: @Amitd I attempted to name my textbox and try using Controls.Find, but neither Controls or Control.Find exist in forms.

Comment: hmm what does "this" refer to in your code? Is it form or another control?

Comment: @Amitd Ignore my previous comment, your solution works well. The this just refers to the addition of the textbox to the form, at least that's what my limited understanding of the matter tells me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a name to the textbox and later use [ControlCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve it
Try this

```
TextBox playertextbox = new TextBox();
playertextbox.Location = new Point(460, 200);
playertextbox.Name = "playertxtBox"; // Add some name
this.Controls.Add(playertextbox);
```

Then use the name in the button click handler or similar :

```
 //Use that name to search here
 TextBox playertextbox = ((TextBox) this.Controls.Find("playertxtBox",true)[0]); 
 string text = playertextbox.Text;
```